# Calculator functionality using svelte reactivity

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm trying to implement calculator functionality using mathjs library and Svelte. But i cant seem to make the buttons show their value on the display. Im using the input element so that physical and phone keyboards can work. For the result I used the output element.

This works:
[Simple example REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/193d8ed7893c472c8443857df4a22983?version=3.59.1)

This does not:

App.svelte

```
    <script>
  import Display from "./components/Display.svelte"
  
  
</script>

<main class="container">
  <Display />
</main>

<style>
</style>
```

Display.svelte

```html
<!-- Svelte -->
<script>
  import { evaluate } from 'mathjs'
  import Button from "./Button.svelte"
  
  
  let total = 0
  let numberInput = ''

  // private function
  function addToInput(value) {
    numberInput += value
  }

  const clear = () => {
    total = 0
    numberInput = ""
  }

  function calculate() {
    if (numberInput !== "") {
      numberInput = result().toString()
    }
  }

  function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
    return string.split(search).join(replace);
  }

  function formatString(value) {
    return replaceAll(replaceAll(value, "*", "x"), "/", "÷");
  }

  // computed
  let result = () => {
    if (!isNaN(numberInput.slice(-1))) {
      return evaluate(numberInput)
    }
    return evaluate(numberInput.slice(0, -1))
  }





  // function addToInput(value){
  //   prompt(value)
  //   console.log(value)
  //   numberInput += value
  // }


  

  $: if (
    numberInput !== "" &&
    !isNaN(numberInput.slice(-1)) &&
    numberInput != result()
  ) {
    total = result().toString();
  }
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="screen-display">

    <!-- type="number"
    class=""
    placeholder={numberInput}
    value={numberInput} -->
    <input id="arithmetic" bind:value={numberInput} />
    <output name="result" for="arithmetic" placeholder="Results">{total}</output>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container numpad">
  <Button setting><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
      <path d="M19.4 15a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 .33 1.82l.06.06a2 2 0 0 1 0 2.83 2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.06-.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.82-.33 1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1 1.51V21a2 2 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.09A1.65 1.65 0 0 0 9 19.4a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.82.33l-.06.06a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0 2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l.06-.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 .33-1.82 1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.51-1H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2-2h.09A1.65 1.65 0 0 0 4.6 9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-.33-1.82l-.06-.06a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83 2 2 0 0 1 2.83 0l.06.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.82.33H9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1-1.51V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.09a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1 1.51 1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.82-.33l.06-.06a2 2 0 0 1 2.83 0 2 2 0 0 1 0 2.83l-.06.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-.33 1.82V9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.51 1H21a2 2 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-.09a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.51 1z" />
    </svg></Button>
  <Button gray="true">FACT</Button>
  <Button gray="true" on:click={()=> addToInput('^')}>a<sup style="margin-inline-start: .2em">b</sup></Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('7')}>7</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('8')}>8</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('9')}>9</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('/')} >&divide;</Button>
  <Button orange="true">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
      <path d="M21 4H8l-7 8 7 8h13a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z" />
      <line x1="18" y1="9" x2="12" y2="15" />
      <line x1="12" y1="9" x2="18" y2="15" />
    </svg>
  </Button>
  <Button dark="false" orange="true">AC</Button>
  <Button gray="true">M&plus;</Button>
  <Button gray="true">M&minus;</Button>
  <Button gray="true"><svg id="ei4kL3yKbWI1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" style="background-color:transparent; transform: translateY(-8px);">
      <rect width="30" height="30" rx="0" ry="0" transform="translate(136.15 105)" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" />
      <rect width="30" height="30" rx="0" ry="0" transform="translate(136.149972 154.448797)" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" />
      <line x1="-15" y1="0" x2="35" y2="0" transform="translate(141 144)" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" />
    </svg></Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('4')}>4</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('5')}>5</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('6')}>6</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('*')}>&times;</Button>
  <Button gray="true">&#8592;</Button>
  <Button gray="true">&#8594;</Button>
  <Button gray="true">MR</Button>
  <Button gray="true">MC</Button>
  <Button gray="true" on:click={()=> addToInput('√')}>&radic;</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('1')}>1</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('2')}>2</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('3')}>3</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('4')}>&minus;</Button>
  <Button gray="true">Exp</Button>
  <Button gray="true">Ans</Button>
  <Button gray="true">S&lrhar;D</Button>
  <Button gray="true" on:click={()=> addToInput('(')}>&lpar;</Button>
  <Button gray="true" on:click={()=> addToInput(')')}>&rpar;</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('%')}>&percnt;</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('0')}>0</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('.')}>&sdot;</Button>
  <Button on:click={()=> addToInput('+')}>&plus;</Button>
  <Button gray="true" largeBtn="true">&equals;</Button>
</div>
<style>
  .numpad {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, var(--width));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, var(--height));
    gap: 1.3rem 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }



  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    font-size: 2.7rem;

    margin-block-end: 1.8rem;
  }

  ::selection {
    color: lch(89.4 5.7 194);
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .screen-display {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 40vh;
    outline: none;
    border: none;

    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: lch(89.4 5.7 194);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* align-items: center; */
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 1.2rem;
  }

  .wrapper {}

  #arithmetic {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;

    align-self: flex-start;

    margin-inline-start: 1.8em;
    margin-block-start: 0.8em;
  }

  output {
    all: unset;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    align-self: flex-end;

    margin-inline-end: 1.8em;
    margn-block-end: 0.8em;
  }
</style>
```

Button.svelte

```html
    <script>
  import Button from './Button.svelte'
  export let isdisabled = false
  export let dark = true
  export let orange = false
  export let gray = false
  export let setting = false
  export let largeBtn = false
  
  
  


</script>
<button type="button" disabled={isdisabled} aria-label="button" class:dark class:orange class:setting class:gray class:largeBtn value>
  <slot />
</button>

<style lang="scss">
  button {
    all: unset;

    --dropshadow: lch(3.5 1.2 302);

    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px var(--dropshadow));
    width: var(--width);
    height: var(--height);
    text-align: center;

    color: var(--btn-clr);
    background-color: var(--btn-bg);
    border-top: 1.5px solid var(--btn-top);
    margin-block-end: 2rem;
    margin-inline-end: 1.8rem;

    transition: all;


    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      transform: translateY(3px);
    }

  }


  .dark {
    background-color: var(--btn-dark-bg);
    color: var(--btn-dark-clr);
    border-top: 1.5px solid var(--btn-dark-top);


    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: var(--btn-dark-bg-hov);

    }
  }

  .orange {
    background-color: var(--btn-orange-bg);
    color: var(--btn-orange-clr);
    border-top: 1px solid var(--btn-orange-top);

    /* filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px lch(28.9 25.4 47)); */

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: var(--btn-orange-bg-hov);

    }
  }

  .gray {
    background-color: var(--btn-gray-bg);
    color: var(--btn-gray-clr);
    border-top: 1px solid var(--btn-gray-top);

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: var(--btn-gray-bg-hov);

    }
  }

  .setting {
    background-color: var(--btn-setting-bg);
    color: var(--btn-setting-clr);
    border-top: 1px solid var(--btn-setting-top);

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: var(--btn-setting-bg-hov);

    }
  }

  .largeBtn {
    width: var(--large);
    grid-column: span 2;
    margin-inline: auto;
  }
</style>
```

I would be grateful for any input (pun intended).:svelte:
Here is the [Live Website](https://sensational-chaja-a94eb8.netlify.app)

I expected the button values to appear ont the input and the output reactively gives the expression evaluation. At first i had the numpad and display in different components and used `createEventDispatcher` to set up a custom event to keep track of the input in the screen display. I tried appending with += but it made no difference. ChatGPT was not hepful.

Comment: Why not make a simple example that shows the problem?

Comment: Here it is [Working Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/193d8ed7893c472c8443857df4a22983?version=3.59.1) but when i implement it in my calculator app, it does not work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I meant to reduce the code of the example that doesn't work... the problem might be in the `Button` component from which you didn't share the code

Comment: I have added the Button.Svelte and even App.svelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<button>` element inside the component needs an `on:click` without handler

###### Button.svelte

```
<button type="button" disabled={isdisabled} aria-label="button" ... on:click >
  <slot />
</button>
```

so that listening on the component works

```
<Button on:click={()=> addToInput('4')}>4</Button>
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't realise it was this simple.